# awesomewm hangs on login on AWS + NICE DCV

Tags: window-manager, aws, awesome

Having used awesome wm for years, I am now facing problems wanting to use it on my corporate machine (aws instance with graphical interface via Nice DCV). Upon logging in, i.e. typing in the password, nothing happens but ubuntu hangs in the login screen.

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this?

On reddit someone posted

> Most likely Awesome WM does not support the XDG autostart specification, you may need to add /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dcv/dcvxdgagentlauncher to the session startup scripts

but I have no idea what that means or how to do that.

Help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 20.04 LTS, EC2 Aws instance, graphical client is nice dcv https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/dcv/latest/adminguide/what-is-dcv.html